# I want to delete a user from a list that ID's and rows change dynamically using Selenium in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am in a web page with names and I have the Users name Test User99. I want to use a selenium Webdriver/C# command to find that User and click the delete button next to him. There are ID's but they are generated dynamically and the User and the button have different Id's and cells. The Row could be different each time.

Comment: Share the HTML of the Users table. Also have you tried anything?

Comment: Unfortunately I cant share even the HTML for this project. I have looked at trying to look through the source and parse but I do not know how to code that. If anyone else does and could help me thta would be appreciated to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            string pagesource = wd.PageSource;
            int username = pagesource.IndexOf("what you are looking for");
            string anything = pagesource.Substring(username - 60, 70);
            string buttonID = anything.Substring(anything.IndexOf("an ID"), 10);
            string buttonID2 = buttonID.Substring(0, buttonID.IndexOf('_'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use XPath to find the user name and then walk the DOM to get the delete button, but without the HTML, I cannot provide a concrete answer

Comment: I think xpath would change. The User does not always reside at the same place in the grid? Sorry I am very new to xpath and what i have researched showed that I would need information on where.

Comment: Properly written xpath will work no matter where the user is located in the grid. I think what Robbie had in mind was something like: //*[text()='Test User99'] - going from that node you should be able to find the delete button.

Comment: Yea, something like //*[text()='Test User99']/following-sibling/button  but without seeing the DOM I cannot give a concrete example.

Comment: @user1622681 -I think you need to do some reading about XPath is before making comments